# Pass multiple commands over SSH and return output

Tags: ssh, command, output

I am trying to write a short script that will SSH to a remote server, execute a few commands, and return the output prices and such, which I will parse locally.

So far, I am trying this, but it just hangs:

ssh user@server_name 'redis-cli; hmget IBM last updated; quit' > output.txt

The actual output will be 3 lines:

1. "1234.56"
2. "IBM"
3. "11/13/2020 17:44:02"

Any way to run these commands and capture those 3 lines?

Thanks!

Comment: So you fist login to the server then take the data you want ?also does it require password ?

Comment: No, I have ssh keys set up.  So, just ssh user@server_name

Answer (score 0):

Ok so what I would do is write a script which does the following :

1)connects to sever
And after makes sure it is connected (u can use a sleep command)

2. Save output of commands to the file:

   ```
   Command1 > output.txt
   Command2 >> output.txt
   ```

“>” is used to first create the file and “>>” to add more data to the same file

And so on

3. send file back to local machine using `scp` (or any other tool you want)

In this case it’s really simple so command would be :

```
scp “output.txt” localuser@localserver:Destination/
```

Comment: Ok I’m glad you did  Plz consider accepting my answer do community know your problem is solved and both me and you increase our reputation